# Windows 8 GPT Encryption

Tags: security, encryption

I have to run encryption for HIPAA Compliance and ran into a snag. I have a Windows 8.1 Home with GPT Based drive.

It does not have Bitlocker nor TPM, and VerCrypt doesn't support GPT Partitions.

Does anyone know of a program that will encrypt this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks! That actually makes perfect sense! I will try something else.